# Count True State Tset property Items inside a component

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to count "True" Tset Items inside a component?

What I did:

```
  TColorItem = (ms_red, ms_blue, ms_green, ms_yellow);
  TColorItems = set of TColorItem;
```

I have a component and I can choose from the `TColorItems`

```
 TProperty = class(TCollectionItem)
 private
   FModuleItem: TColorItems;  
   procedure SetColorItem(const Value: TColorItems);    
 published
   property ColorTypes: TColorItems read FColorItem write SetColorItem;

 procedure SetColorItem(const Value: TColorItems);
 begin
   FColorItem := Value;
 end;
```

The component has a lot of TCollectionItem, all the Items has different Colortypes. (The component is connected to a checklistbox in on the main form)

For example:

**AColorItem**

- ms_red: false
- ms_blue : true
- ms_green: true
- ms_yellow: false

**BColorItem**

- ms_red: true
- ms_blue : true
- ms_green: true
- ms_yellow: false

I want to count the "true states". If count is > 1, I want to do something...

The TProperty is in a TCollection which has Item property...

I can reach it with...

```
var
  C: integer
  vItem: TColorItem 
begin
   for ...
   PropertyCollection.Items[C].ColorTypes
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you tell (in code) whether a particular ColorItem is an AColorItem or a BColorItem one?

Comment: Err?  You said f.i. that ms_red should return False for an AColorItem but True for a BColorItem.   Perhaps I'm missing your point ...

Comment: Vocabulary lesson: The number of items in a set is known as the set's *cardinality*.

Comment: That Delphi has no Cardinality intrinsic is a very significant omission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the set is empty by comparing it to the empty set `[]`.  You can count the number of items using a function (as below) :

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses SysUtils;

type
  TColorItem = (ms_red, ms_blue, ms_green, ms_yellow);
  TColorItems = set of TColorItem;

procedure WriteSetContents(const AColorItems : TColorItems);
begin
  WriteLn('Set contains...');
  if AColorItems = [] then begin
    WriteLn('Nothing');
    Exit;
  end;
  if ms_red in AColorItems then WriteLn('Red');
  if ms_blue in AColorItems then WriteLn('Blue');
  if ms_green in AColorItems then WriteLn('Green');
  if ms_yellow in AColorItems then WriteLn('Yellow');
end;

function GetSetCount(const AColorItems : TColorItems) : integer;
var
  ci : TColorItem;
begin
  result := 0;
  for ci := Low(TColorItem) to High(TColorItem) do
    if ci in AColorItems then Inc(result);
end;

var
  cis : TColorItems;
begin
  cis := [];
  WriteLn(Format('Set has %d Items', [GetSetCount(cis)]));
  WriteSetContents(cis);
  WriteLn;
  cis := cis + [ms_red];
  WriteLn(Format('Set has %d Items', [GetSetCount(cis)]));
  WriteSetContents(cis);
  WriteLn;
  cis := cis + [ms_green, ms_yellow];
  WriteLn(Format('Set has %d Items', [GetSetCount(cis)]));
  WriteSetContents(cis);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: If you're looking for more optimized (and less straight forward) way, take a look at Bit Twiddling Hacks (https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel)

Comment: @HonzaR Yes, you can do this with bitmasking, but until there is a very good reason to obfuscate things like that I would always prefer a more readable implementation.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more, I thought it was wort mentioning if someone needs to improve this performance-wise. (Depends on the use-case)